# Check if download link is dead in php?

Tags: php

If I get title of the page, I can tell the download link is active or dead.

For example: "**Free online storage**" is title of dead link and "**[file name]**" is the title of active link **(mediafire)**. But my page takes too long to respond, so is there any other way to check if a download link is active or dead?

That is what i have done:

```
<?php

function getTitle($Url){
$str = file_get_contents($Url);
if(strlen($str)>0){
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Comment: sorry, i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not perform a GET request, which downloads the whole page/file, but HEAD request, which gets only the HTTP headers, and check if the status is 200, and the content-type is not text/html

Comment: Just returning a 200 response is not enough; many valid links will continue to return "200" after they change into porn / gambling portals when the former owner fails to renew.

Domain squatters typically ensure that every URL in their domains returns 200.

Comment: Well, actually the solution is domain-specific. I don't think general solution could exists, as the computer cannot know what is a valid page and what's not for all cases in Internet, but for specific site, a HEAD request may serve well.

Comment: Can it be more detail? Which code should I use to request header only, and how do I get title from it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
function url_validate($link)
{
    #[url]http://www.example.com/determining-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/[/url]
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); //follow up to 10 redirections - avoids loops
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    preg_match_all("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/",$data,$matches);

    $code = end($matches[1]);

    if(!$data) 
    {
        return(false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if($code==200) 
        {
            return(true);
        } 
        elseif($code==404) 
        {
            return(false);
        }
    }
}
```

You can safely use any cURL library function. It is legitimate and thus would not regarded as a hacking attempt. The only requirement is that your web hosting company has cURL extension installed, which is very likely.

Comment: `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` is a better way to get the HTTP code

Answer (score 0):

`cURL` should do the job. You can check the headers returned and the text content as well if you want.